# How can I use Ampscript to replace a variable or string that occurs many times, with an incrementally increasing number?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email

We are using concatenated tracking tags, on our links.

One of the values in the concatenation is a unique identifying number which needs to be manually replaced in each email that is sent. E.g. L01, L02, L03 etc.

```
<a href="%%=Redirect(Concat('https://www.google.com?TrackingCounter=',@TrackingCounter,'&_OtherTrackingStuff'))=%%">
```

In some emails there are a lot of these to be replaced, and it would be great to have an automated solution. I have tried to achieve this but the loop keeps going and replaces all instances of the variable with L100.

```
SET @TrackingCounter = 'L'
FOR @Variable2 = 1 TO 100 DO
 CONCAT(@TrackingCounter,@Variable2)
NEXT SET @TrackingCounter = CONCAT(@TrackingCounter,@Variable2)
```

Do I need to know the number of times the @TrackingCounter variable occurs, so that it does not loop over and over?

I don't know, and googling has not helped me to work out, how to achieve something like the following:

```
FIND HOW MANY INSTANCES OF @TrackingCounter, set this as @TrackingCounterNumber

FOR @i = 1 TO @TrackingCounterNumber DO 
 REPLACE(@TrackingCounter,@TrackingCounter+@i)
NEXT @i
```

Can someone please suggest the most effective way to achieve this?

Comment: So to get this right: You have an email, there are multiple links of these. Each link should have its own unique trackingnumber, attached to the end of the link by parameter. This should be dynamic and the number of links in each email can vary dynamicly?

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick that's correct

Comment: The content you set and the links you are setting in the newsletter - do you have this data in a dataextension or are content creators responsible for setting these links inside the newsletter?

Comment: It will be a mixture. Some content blocks will be pulled in and their hrefs automatically populated from DEs, and some will be manually updated. All hrefs will be concatenated in the same way tho, regardless of where they originate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may not be the most elegant option, but its the first that comes to mind and is fairly simple to set up.

First you would create a Code Snippet Content Block with the following AMPScript in it:

```js
%%[ 
    IF EMPTY(@Num) THEN
      SET @Num = 1
    ELSE
      SET @Num = ADD(@Num,1) 
    ENDIF

    SET @TrackingCounter = CONCAT(@TrackingCounterRaw,@Num)
]%%
```

This will basically add 1 to the variable every time its called.

e.g.

```js
SET TC = L
SET N = 1
//does Add N + 1 (1 + 1) = 2 ==> TC + N ( L + 2 = L2)
//does Add N + 1 (2 + 1) = 3 ==> TC + N ( L + 3 = L3)
//does Add N + 1 (3 + 1) = 4 ==> TC + N ( L + 4 = L4)
```

Then every time you have a new link, you would just call this content block prior to the link.  Something like:

```js
%%[ /* initial set up ampscript block */
    SET @TrackingCounterRaw = "L"
    SET @Num = 1
   SET @url = "https://www.google.com"
]%%
 ........
%%[ ContentBlockByKey('TrackingCounterNumber_CB') ]%%
<a href="%%=REDIRECTTO(CONCAT(@url,'?tc=',@TrackingCounter))=%%">link 1</a>
.........
%%[ ContentBlockByKey('TrackingCounterNumber_CB') ]%%
<a href="%%=REDIRECTTO(CONCAT(@url,'?tc=',@TrackingCounter))=%%">link 2</a>
```

This will then set the tracking counter number to '+1' for each recurring link without having to write out the add and concat code multiple times.

Which would output:

```js
//Output:
//Link 1: https://www.google.com?tc=L1
//Link 2: https://www.google.com?tc=L2
```

Comment: The only option that came to my mind was, this would be very weird when the emails  have varying links, and kind of tidious. What came to my mind was something, where i do not know if its achievable or not. If you would have the web analytics connector and would set a variable there including an ampscript statement that would not be printed but increases the number by one, it could be possible. But i dont know if web analytics connector has the possibility to inherit ampscript that would be called each time the link is processed. Therefore i stopped because i thought->no good solution possible

Comment: According to OP this is just once for each link, regardless if they go to same place or not. As to WAC as a possible solution, to my knowledge it would not iterate through continually adding, it would just give the same single output for each.

Comment: Yeah thought so :/ Great solution though. To make it clearer i would add that the contentblock has the Key 'TrackingCounterNumber_CB'. Otherwise readers might not understand that this is a block hosted outside of the newsletter

Comment: @Gortonington many thanks for taking the time to answer my question. So if we are having to code manually then there is nothing gained because we can manually add the number, instead of calling the Ampscript block, but in our more automated emails this will work. I am off to test this out :)